# PowerPC Linux machine for PHP hosting always throws "Balloc() allocation exceeds list boundary" error

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, powerpc

I've a copy of Codeigniter framework on the server

When I run the code on the server it always throws following error

**Fatal error: Balloc() allocation exceeds list boundary in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/project/system/core/Benchmark.php on line 92**

I've already rigorously googled this error , I am not sure but the issue looks same as [thread 1](http://www.archivum.info/php.bugs/2013-02/00454/Bug-62581-%28Fbk-gt-NoF%29-Fatal-error-Balloc%28%29-allocation-exceeds-list-boundary.html) , since there's calculation involved during the Benchmark process or there's memory hog issue as mentioned in [thread 2](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=23360) , cause this server when up mirrors the whole source code in htdocs/ folder for performance reason , htdocs/ is not a space on HDD but a memory space .

Following are the other server details

Web server = Apache/2.2.22(Unix)

PHP version = 5.4.3

Kindly suggest me other options to look up for solving this issue.

Comment: [This bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47980) could be related.

Answer (score 0):

Currently PHP is designed for INTEL processor, and currently cross compiling is not supportted by PHP. INTEL and ARM processors are little-endian and PowerPC is the BIG-ENDIAN.. I think this is the reason of you problem.. when Compiling your PHP, prepare it for BIG endian technology (In PHP.ini file I think there is a such a option)..

As my Strace debugging analysis, I see PHP time function is source of the problem..

I wish it helps...

Answer (score -1):

Check the last comment on: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41951

I ran a test program on the target device to determine the sizes of int, long, size_t, ssize_t etc. and modified main/php_config.h accordingly.

also I set ac_cv_c_bigendian_php=yes php_cv_cc_rpath="no" while running configure. This might differ according to your target system architecture.